# How to get data in csv format from xml data

Tags: python, xml

I have been trying to write xml code to retrieve the data in csv format

When I use `i.text` it gives all data in one line
I am expecting data should be in csv format

**My code :**

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data='''

<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
        <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>

'''

xml_parser = ET.fromstring(data)
count_of_child_element = []
cnt = 0
for i in xml_parser.getiterator():
    if i.tag == 'food':
        count_of_child_element.append(cnt)
        cnt = cnt + 1

for indx in range(len(count_of_child_element)):
    for x in xml_parser[indx]:
        print(x.text,end=' ')
        print()
```

Expected output :

```
Belgian Waffles,$5.95,Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup,650
Strawberry Belgian Waffles,$7.95,Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream,900
```

Comment: Why in world would you expect the data to be in CSV format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give the output you are looking for:

```py
xml_parser = ET.fromstring(data)

for indx in range(len(xml_parser)):
    for x in range(len(xml_parser[indx])):
        e = xml_parser[indx][x]
        print(e.text, end="")
        if x != len(xml_parser[indx]) - 1:
            print(",", end="")
    print()
```

Comment: can you elaborate your code